# Вопрос по теме "Множества"

Tags: python, множества

```
>>> bri = set(['Бразилия', 'Россия', 'Индия'])
>>> 'Индия' in bri
True
>>> 'США' in bri
False
>>> bric = bri.copy()
>>> bric.add('Китай')
>>> bric.issuperset(bri)
True
>>> bri.remove('Россия')
>>> bri & bric # OR bri.intersection(bric)
{'Бразилия', 'Индия'}
```

Доброго времени суток всем. Кто может подробно расписать по пунктам что происходит в этой операции?
Мне для общего понимания хода вещей.

Comment: Которые из этих 8 команд для вас непонятные?

Comment: Начиная с 6-ой строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Состояние после первых 5 команд:

```
In[6]: bri
Out[6]: {'Бразилия', 'Индия', 'Россия'}
In[7]: bric
Out[7]: {'Бразилия', 'Индия', 'Китай', 'Россия'}
```

6. `bric.issuperset(bri)`

   *«Разве* `bric` *является надмножеством* `bri`*?»*.
   Когда `True`, это значит, что каждый элемент из `bri` тоже находится в `bric`.
7. `bri.remove('Россия')`

   Элемент `'Россия'` удалится из множества `bri`.
   Состояние после этого:

   ```
   In[9]: bri
   Out[9]: {'Бразилия', 'Индия'}
   In[10]: bric
   Out[10]: {'Бразилия', 'Индия', 'Китай', 'Россия'}
   ```
8. `bri & bric # OR bri.intersection(bric)`

   *«Пересечение множеств* `bri` *и* `bric`*».*
   Множество общих элементов из `bri` и `bric`; другими словами, множество тех элементов, которые находятся так в множестве `bri`, как и в множестве `bric`.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что изменения во множестве отразятся и на надмножестве, но наоборот проделать такое нельзя? Он же типа ссылается на него, а не создает копию

Comment: Нет, эти множества *независимые друг от друга,* т. к. вы применили метод `.copy()` на создание второго. Когда бы вы просто сделали `bric = bri`, то существовало бы только одно множество с двумя именами, значит, всякое изменение с помощью одного имени  проявилось бы тоже в другом имени.

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо за все разъяснения :)

Comment: @ImranDishade, не стоит. ;-)